# How to fetch all assets from iPhone apart from camera roll?

Tags: ios, swift, photo

How to fetch assets from all albums including images and videos ?

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
```

This code will fetch only images from camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to fetch all assets from iPhone.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self as PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver)

        if fetchResult == nil {

            let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
            fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
        }
```

Comment: This will fetch all images and videos but not all from other albums example .sync albums.

Answer (score 0):

we can fetch all photos including sync albums and user albums.

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.includeAssetSourceTypes = [.typeUserLibrary, .typeiTunesSynced, .typeCloudShared]
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
```

fetchResult will be having all photos and videos in all albums.